# How can I group CSS grid items together in categories?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-experience

I am trying to replicate the effect found here at the [Google Cloud developer cheat sheet](https://googlecloudcheatsheet.withgoogle.com/).

[image: Current display]

Currently my larger boxes that display the name of the category, and their associated smaller boxes all fill in the grid linearly as in the picture below. I know I should probably be setting the position of each box individually or rearranging the order of the boxes in the array based on the screen size but can't wrap my head around even beginning a solution. How should I approach this?

```css
#mapView {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  background-color: #f9fafb;
}

.hidden #mapView {
  display: none;
}

.capabilityContainer {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.technologyContainer {
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML here -->
```

Comment: Please revise the demo snippet above to add some HTML. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you'll find a robust CSS-only solution, though. There's probably a masonry-like script behind the Google UI you linked.

Comment: Agreed. Pretty sure it's not possible with CSS without a great deal of manual intervention. Javascript would be optimal.

Comment: I learned from the Google cheat sheet that ALL squares, both large (h/w `336px`) and small (h/w `112px`), are `position: absolute` with hardcoded `top` and `left` locations in the main container. Go Google!! Who needs JS?